# Conflict pyinstaller vs pathlib --> removing pathlib causes deletion of anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, pathlib

I get the following error message when using the pyinstaller to convert python file to .exe:

The 'pathlib' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller. Please remove this package using conda remove then try again.

My python version is currently 3.10.9
Pyinstaller version 5.11.0

When I follow the advice to remove pathlib, pyinstaller works perfectly but my anaconda navigator gets deleted. I always have to re-install it, but then again pyinstaller is not working, because pathlib gets newly installed.
Does someone faces the same issue and has a solution?

Edit: I don't need the anaconda navigator for the pyinstaller application itself, but would like to keep the navigator since I use it to open programs like VS Code, Jupyter etc and its not very convenient that it gets deleted just because of the conflict between pathlib and pyinstaller.

Comment: Why do you need anaconda navigator in a pyinstaller application?

Comment: I don't need the anaconda navigator explicitly for the pyinstaller application, but I like working with the navigator for opening my programs like VS Code, Jupyter Notebook to create code. Sorry, I should make this more clear in my question

Comment: so then the easy solution would be to only install pyinstaller into virtual enviornments when you need to and don't install it into the enviornemtn you use for the navigator.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:
Instead of using conda remove pathlib, I manually deleted the folder for the pathlib package in the anaconda3/Lib/site-packages folder. Doing this, anaconda navigator is not deleted, just the not needed old version of pathlib and pyinstaller works normally.